# How to Make Square Corner Things?

Tags: css

Really vague question, I know, but I don't know how to describe them... Basically, I want these:

[image: What I want]

I'm talking about the corner things in red. What's the easiest way to achieve this? Obviously, you could just make individual divs in those shapes, but I feel like getting them in the positions you want, even when everything re-sizes and stuff, would be a pain. Is that the only way?

Comment: Maybe try css `border-image`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here an approach that might be useful.  Add two pseudo elements, one with top and bottom borders and the second with left and right borders of a certain color (white) such that they "white out" the original border (blue in this case).

This approach is pure CSS and no extra mark-up is involved.

```css
div {
  font-size: 4.00em;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  top: 25%;
  bottom: 25%;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div>Box Text</div>
```

Comment: Better than mine, +1 I should have done borders and not the background which of course overlaps the text.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  }

.ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  }

.ur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  }

.ll {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  }

.lr {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <span>text</span>
  <div class="ul"></div>
  <div class="ur"></div>
  <div class="ll"></div>
  <div class="lr"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the `border-image` solution mentioned by *Matthew* in the comment. Just for the record, there are lot's of good answers here. Not to mention `border-image` will probably not work in all browsers.

[Can I use **border-image**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image)

Here is a solution using an inline SVG.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Waiting+for+the+Sunrise);

div {
  width: 275px;
  height: 155px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 6.2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Waiting for the Sunrise', cursive;
}

.inline-svg {
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="275px" height="155px" viewBox="0 0 275 155" enable-background="new 0 0 275 155" xml:space="preserve"><path fill="#ff0000" d="M0.5,38.5v-38h57v15h-42v23H0.5z M260.5,38.5h15v-38h-59v15h44V38.5z M260.5,112.5v28h-44v15h59v-43H260.5z M15.5,112.5h-15v43h57v-15h-42V112.5z"/></svg>') 2% stretch;
  min-width: 50%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .inline-svg {
    width: 360px;
    height: 265px;
  }
  div {
    font-size: 9.4em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-svg">Text</div>
```